kibana list all data views when the kibana api is not available
Is there any way to get data views from kibana dev tools or kibana web front-end?
In web-front I have to manually replace one and one to get the uuid.
I just need to dump a json and use as a lookup table when pushing new grafana dashboards to prod.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/data-views-api-get-all.html
In prod I do not have any access to kibana api's designated port,
This the call in test:
curl -X GET kibana.test.xxxxxx.yyy:5601/api/data_views
But when I try in kibana dev tools which I use to verify the elastic api calls, api, /api, nor :6531/api for kibana itself are not available:
